# Firebase dataSnapshot.getValue(Subclass.class) function never returns

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to obtain value from Firebase for two different children of the "users" that are "sellers" and "customers". Also these children has children that IDs of the sellers or customers.

Seller and Customer are subclasses of the User class and I have implemented all setters and getters. Here is my code that cant obtain value from database:

```
public class DatabaseWrapper {

    private final static DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    private final static DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child("users");
    private final static DatabaseReference productsRef = ref.child("products");
    private static Object retrieverObject = null;

    public static User getUser(String type, String id) throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
        usersRef.child(type).child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Never returns getValue(Subclass.class)
                    if (type.equals("customers"))
                        retrieverObject = dataSnapshot.getValue(Customer.class);
                    else
                        retrieverObject = dataSnapshot.getValue(Seller.class);
                done.countDown();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
          });
        done.await();
        return (User)retrieverObject;

    }
```

I deliberately make it sync code to see problem.
If I use `getValue(User.class)` instead of `getValue(Customer.class)` and `getValue(Seller.class)` it works but this usage obviously doesn't obtain fields that are in subclasses.
So the question is how can I retrieve subclass item from Firebase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

Who has similar problem that is deserializing objects from Firebase, do not forget to write an empty constructor. I had only constructors with parameters, then I added empty parameter constructor to subclasses, it worked.